# Gulp - Unexpected character '@' (1:0) while parsing style\main.scss

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have gulp installed and this is the error that I get. Can someone help me out please?

I have tried deleting the node_modules and did the npm-install. But it still doesnt work.

This is how my gulpfile looks like.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var scssify = require('scssify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var path = require('path');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var gls = require('gulp-live-server');
var commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
var sass = require('gulp-sass') ;
var notify = require("gulp-notify") ;
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var lodash = require('lodash');

var config = {
     sassPath: './gssp/client/style',
     bowerDir: './bower_components'
};

function onError(error) {
    gutil.log(error.message);
    console.log(error.toString());
}

var cli = commandLineArgs([
    { name: 'packages', alias: 'p', type: String, defaultValue: [""], multiple:true }
]);

var options = cli.parse();

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    return bower()
         .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))
});

gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/fonts/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('embeddedIcons', function() {
    return gulp.src('./gssp/src/leafs/icon/fonts/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src/leafs/icon/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('css',['bower'], function() {
    return gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
             outputStyle: 'compressed',
             includePaths: [
                 './gssp/client/style',
                 config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
                 config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss',
             ]
         })
        .on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('runLiveServer', function () {
    var server = gls.new(['gssp/index.js', options.packages.join(" ")]);
    server.start();

    gulp.watch(['./core/**/*.js','./gssp/**/*.scss'], ['build']);

    gulp.watch(['./dist/bundle.js'], function (file) {
        server.notify.apply(server, [file]);
    });
});

gulp.task('copyStatics', function() {
    return gulp.src('./core/server/public/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});


gulp.task('build',['copyStatics', 'icons', 'embeddedIcons', 'css'], function () {
    return browserify({
        entries: './gssp/client/index.js',
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
        debug: true
    })
            .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]})
      .bundle()
        .on('error', onError)
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('run-wrapper', function(done) {
    var server = spawn('node', ['serviceWrapper.js'], {stdio: ['inherit']});
    server.stderr.on('data', function(data){
        process.stderr.write(data);
    });

    server.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
    server.unref();
});

gulp.task('run', function(done) {
    console.log(lodash.concat);
    var child = spawn('node', lodash.union(['gssp/index.js'], options.packages), {stdio: ['inherit']});

    child.stderr.on('data', function(data){
        process.stderr.write(data);
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./gssp/src/**/*.{js,jsx}', ['build']);
  gulp.watch('./gssp/src/**/*.scss', ['build']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
    runSequence('build', ['run-wrapper', 'runLiveServer'],done)
});

gulp.task('start', function(done) {
    runSequence('build', ['run-wrapper', 'run'], done);
});

gulp.task('default', ['start']);
```

This is how my bower file looks like.

```
{
  "name": "gssp-sales",
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "authors": [
    "Vamshi Gudipati"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "bootstrap-sass-official#~3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#~4.5.0"
  }
}
```

I have gulp installed and this is the error that I get. Can someone help me out please?

I have tried deleting the node_modules and did the npm-install. But it still doesnt work.

This is how my gulpfile looks like

Comment: Could you share the style\main.scss, as it's likely the error is with that file?

Comment: Please provide snippet for the style/main.scss file

Comment: Thanks for watching out guys. Everything worked fine until we wanted to move from webpack to gulp. I dont know if I'm missing something. This is my bower.json

Comment: Thanks for watching out guys. Everything worked fine until we wanted to move from webpack to gulp. I dont know if I'm missing something. This is my bower.json
http://pasteboard.co/ESwfnI.png
This is my main.scss
http://pasteboard.co/GJu0tQ.png
This is my error log
http://pasteboard.co/GM9q3N.png
Error on line 2 it says

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your `font-awesome.css` file in dist/css and see in the first block @font-face where the src is pointing to. Make sure it is pointing to the correct directory where you have extracted the font-awesome fonts and the error will go away.

For me I had to do something like this in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('build-fonts', function(){
    return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/fonts')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
})
```